# Getting response header from initial page load request without making request.

Tags: javascript, http, header, request

There is a custom response header that I want to check and use that come from the initial page load request (the request browser send when we type in the url).

Is there a way for me to access that header as a script that sits on the page WITHOUT making another request?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258705/how-can-i-read-the-current-headers-without-making-a-new-request-with-js (I won't close this because that question is closed, for the unlikely event that there is an answer that's not "no, it's not possible.")

Comment: This is what I kinda expected, I just posted this question to see if someone know whether the unicorn exists.