# How to read request headers in React?

Tags: reactjs, header, query-string, request-headers

When the React app. is loaded, I am able to get the query param from the current page's url through `window.location.search'. Similarly, I want to read the request headers. How to read the request headers in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get request headers of the page in React, without sending a http request via javascript.

Refer answers: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354763/how-do-i-get-http-headers-in-react-js](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354763/how-do-i-get-http-headers-in-react-js)
[How can I read the current headers without making a new request with JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258705/how-can-i-read-the-current-headers-without-making-a-new-request-with-js)