# jQuery save landingurl and referealurl as hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming an HTML web form with 2 hidden fields.

## landingurl: the full url where the visitor landed before submitting the form including tracking codes

## referealurl: the full referal url (where the visitor came from)

I want to jquery to save those values in the value fields which are hidden in the form.

I can't figure it out

Comment: How are you expecting to grab the referral url?  Afaik, by default that would be on the page load headers, and javascript wouldn't have access to those.

Comment: how about grabing the landing page url?

Comment: The url of the current page is just `window.location.href`

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is **you can't**. Response headers are not exposed for the current page request. This has been [asked repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258705/how-can-i-read-the-current-headers-without-making-a-new-request-with-js).

Comment: how to save the landing page url or current url in the hidden field before submitting

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the current URL with `window.location.href`, so if you grab the `href` on the landing page, then you have the landing URL.

You can grab the referring URL with `document.referrer`. This also needs to be grabbed on the landing page.

I haven't used jQuery in a while, but I believe the syntax would be something like this:

```
// For this example I have assumed your fields have the IDs landingURL and referralURL.

$('#landingURL').val(window.location.href);

$('#referralURL').val(document.referrer);
```

Now, if the landing page is not the same page as the form, and you need to pass this information along to the form page using only JavaScript in the browser, then I would suggest that you grab the landing page URL and the referral URL as described above and save them in either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Here's an example of how you can do that:

```
// On the landing page:
localStorage.setItem('landingURL', window.location.href);
localStorage.setItem('referralURL', document.referrer);

// On the form page:
$('#landingURL').val(localStorage.getItem('landingURL'));
$('#referralURL').val(localStorage.getItem('referralURL'));
```

Hope that helps!