# Parse response headers of an HTML request in rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, jwt

Is it possible to access response headers of an HTML request sent to the browser via ruby (in controllers)?

**What I am doing?**
I am trying to authenticate a login request using `devise` and `devise-jwt` in a rails app. After successful authentication I am assigned an Authorization token in response headers and redirected to a `after_sign_in_path`. Now on browser I can see the token being received, however I also need the same token issued in the controller action before it goes to the browser.

Upon parsing/logging response headers(`response.headers`) in the controller action(responsible for rendering the same view), i don't see Authorization key at all.

**Alternative**:
Tried using javascript but as it turns out you can only parse response headers of a request initiated by javascript. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258705/how-can-i-read-the-current-headers-without-making-a-new-request-with-js) states the same

Is there a way i can achieve this and not resort to using ajax request method?

Answer (score 0):

An [ActionCongtroller::Base#response](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#method-i-response) object is created by Rails and contains all the information of the HTTP response being built by the controller. This is an instance of [ActionDispatch::Response](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html).  There are various methods for accessing and interacting with the response headers. [`response.headers`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object) is where you would want to add custom response data.

Comment: Hey, thanks but i have been using the same object to find the token, however token is absent in the object but it always reaches the browser